# При сборке Gradle, я получаю ошибку :compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle

Я взял чужой проект и хочу его запустить у себя в Andorid Studio, но на стадии сборки получаю такую ошибку.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Basic_Calculator-task:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':Basic_Calculator-task:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, F:\Android\Basic Calculator\Basic Calculator\task\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@799883b2) before task ':Basic_Calculator-task:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported
```

With --info.

```
> Task :Basic_Calculator-task:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
Task :Basic_Calculator-task:javaPreCompileDebug in Basic_Calculator-task Starting
Caching disabled for task ':Basic_Calculator-task:javaPreCompileDebug' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Skipping task ':Basic_Calculator-task:javaPreCompileDebug' as it is up-to-date.
Task :Basic_Calculator-task:javaPreCompileDebug in Basic_Calculator-task Finished
:Basic_Calculator-task:javaPreCompileDebug (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
```

Но, если я создаю собственный проект таких проблем нет.

gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.hyperskill.calculator"
        minSdkVersion 21
        // DO NOT CHANGE THIS VALUE
        // Because this version related with robolectic version too
        // [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 29 requires Java 9. Tests won't be run on SDK 29 unless explicitly requested.
        //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.edu.AndroidEduTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    def material = "1.3.0-beta01"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material"

    def espressoCore = "3.3.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoCore"

    def testRules = "1.3.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:$testRules"

    def extJUnit = "1.1.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$extJUnit"

    // Robolectric
    // http://robolectric.org
    def robolectric = "4.3.1"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:$robolectric"
}
```

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }

  afterEvaluate {
    if (extensions.findByName("android") != null) {
      android {
        testOptions {
          unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
            all {
              afterTest { TestDescriptor test, TestResult result ->
                if (result.resultType == TestResult.ResultType.FAILURE) {
                  def message = result.exception?.message ?: "Wrong answer"
                  def lines = message.readLines()
                  println "#educational_plugin FAILED + " + lines[0]
                  lines.subList(1, lines.size()).forEach { line ->
                    println "#educational_plugin" + line
                  }
                  // we need this to separate output of different tests
                  println()
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

С [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio) темой, я уже ознакомился и мне ничего не помогло, я пролистал много сайтов в процессе поиска ответа, я обращаюсь к вам после трех дней поиска решения проблемы.

Comment: Такое, вроде, не встречал, ссылку на проект вы не даёте, так что буду гадать - например, проект может быть устаревшим (в плане либ, плагинов) и иметь кофликты со студией/градлом. ПОпробуйте обновить всё, связанное с градлом в проекте - авось заведётся, ну или, хотя бы, ошибка изменится.

Comment: Обновить пробовал, не помогло. Этот проект - это задание на JetBrainsAcademy которое полностью актуальное на данное время. Сам проект по сути калькулятор, который я должен написть сам. Но этот gradle нужен для плохождения тестов.

Comment: Ну... Тут, видимо, придётся наугад перебирать всякие варианты. Начните с установки единой версии Java - вместо `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` укажите `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`. Также проверьте в настройках студии, что она использует 8, а не 9 (или 11) Java. Если не 8 - установите оную и укажите в студии. Также можно попроовать поставить более старую версию студии или перестановить имеющуюся. Ещё InvalidateCacheAndRestart выполнить можно попробовать.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему. Необходимо было установить Bumblebee (2021.1.1) Canary 11 и обновить gradle до версии 7. Так же после обновления gradle до версии 7, при постоенни, я получал уведомление о том что я ипользую устаревшие функции. Так что, я думаю причина была в этом.